# access site and get a search result

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, console-application

I need to access www.skyscanner.com and get the answer to search (set in console application )

I try

```
var url= @"www.skyscanner.com";
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Method = "POST"; 
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequestLogin.GetRequestStream()))
    {              
       var httpResponsee = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
       using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponsee.GetResponseStream()))
       {
           var response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

But i have one error "500", how i can access the site and make a search and get the result?.

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like your POST request has any payload. Skyscanner's server is probably expecting the itinerary details and since it is not getting them it is throwing the 500 error.

I have to add that what you are doing is not the proper way to interact with Skyscanner's service. They have an official API available for which you will need to register and **get an API key** here: http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/AffiliateNetwork

You will then be able to make your application send requests to `http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0`, as documented here:

http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/FlightsLivePricingList